Date parameter errors with Weather.gov API
I am trying to pull historical weather data using the National Weather Service API:
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# Define the base URL for the NWS API
base_url <- "https://api.weather.gov"

# Define the latitude and longitude for the location
latitude <- "40.71"  # Example: New York City
longitude <- "-74.00"

# Construct the API request URL to get the station ID
station_url <- paste0(base_url, "/points/", latitude, ",", longitude)

# Make the request to get the station ID
response <- GET(station_url)

# Parse the JSON response
station_data <- fromJSON(content(response, "text"))

# Extract the station ID
station_id <- station_data$properties$station

# Define the start and end dates for the historical data
start_date <- "2024-10-01"
end_date <- "2024-10-07"

# Construct the API request URL to get historical data
historical_url <- paste0(base_url, "/stations/", station_id, "/observations?start=", start_date, "T00:00:00Z&end=", end_date, "T23:59:59Z")

# Make the request to get the historical data
response <- GET(historical_url)

# Parse the JSON response
historical_data <- fromJSON(content(response, "text"))

# Print the historical weather data
print(historical_data)

# Extract the temperature
temperature <- sapply(historical_data$features, function(x) x$properties$temperature$value)

However, I get a 400 Bad Request response with the following error:
$parameterErrors
    parameter                                   message
1 query.start Query parameter "start" is not recognized
2   query.end   Query parameter "end" is not recognized


station_data$properties$station is NULL for me, maybe did you mean station_data$properties$radarStation?

I haven't succeeded in getting the data yet, but I could avoid the 400 Bad Request response using historical_url <- paste0(base_url, "/stations/", station_id,  "/observations?start=", start_date,  "T00:00:00Z&end=", end_date,   "T23:59:59Z")

The issue may lie in the first section that returns a station ID. If I use a known station ID, such as "0007W", the GET request to the station observation data is successful. The status returned in the response header of the GET request for station ID returns a 301 error (resource permanently moved).

That flow does not seem comply with https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api , though a working request would be for example:
httr::GET(
  paste0("https://api.weather.gov/stations/KNYC/observations?",  
         "start=2024-10-01T00:00:00Z&end=2024-10-07T23:59:59Z") |> 
  httr::content(as = "text")

To get observation from a closest station, perhaps something like this, based on httr2 and sf (to handle GeoJSON responses):
library(httr2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# Define the base URL for the NWS API
base_url <- "https://api.weather.gov"

# Define the latitude and longitude for the location
latitude <- "40.71"  
longitude <- "-74.00"

# get stations for a grid cell, parse GeoJSON response with sf
location_sf <- 
  request(base_url) |> 
  req_url_path("points", paste(latitude, longitude, sep = ",")) |> 
  req_perform() |> 
  resp_body_string() |> 
  read_sf()
glimpse(location_sf)
#> Rows: 1
#> Columns: 19
#> $ id                  <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/points/40.71,-74"
#> $ `@id`               <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/points/40.71,-74"
#> $ `@type`             <chr> "wx:Point"
#> $ cwa                 <chr> "OKX"
#> $ forecastOffice      <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/offices/OKX"
#> $ gridId              <chr> "OKX"
#> $ gridX               <int> 33
#> $ gridY               <int> 35
#> $ forecast            <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/33,35/fore…
#> $ forecastHourly      <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/33,35/fore…
#> $ forecastGridData    <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/33,35"
#> $ observationStations <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/33,35/stat…
#> $ relativeLocation    <chr> "{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"geometry\": { \"type\"…
#> $ forecastZone        <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/NYZ072"
#> $ county              <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/zones/county/NYC061"
#> $ fireWeatherZone     <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/zones/fire/NYZ212"
#> $ timeZone            <chr> "America/New_York"
#> $ radarStation        <chr> "KDIX"
#> $ geometry            <POINT [°]> POINT (-74 40.71)

# get a list of stations, pick one closest to location_sf / input location
closest_obs_station_sf <- 
  location_sf$observationStations |> 
  request() |> 
  req_perform() |> 
  resp_body_string() |> 
  read_sf() |> 
  slice(st_nearest_feature(location_sf, geometry))
glimpse(closest_obs_station_sf)
#> Rows: 1
#> Columns: 11
#> $ id                <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/stations/KNYC"
#> $ `@id`             <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/stations/KNYC"
#> $ `@type`           <chr> "wx:ObservationStation"
#> $ elevation         <chr> "{ \"unitCode\": \"wmoUnit:m\", \"value\": 46.9392 }"
#> $ stationIdentifier <chr> "KNYC"
#> $ name              <chr> "New York City, Central Park"
#> $ timeZone          <chr> "America/New_York"
#> $ forecast          <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/NYZ072"
#> $ county            <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/zones/county/NYC061"
#> $ fireWeatherZone   <chr> "https://api.weather.gov/zones/fire/NYZ212"
#> $ geometry          <POINT [°]> POINT (-73.96667 40.78333)

# observations from station, pluck-map-hoist to extract relevant bits from GeoJSON response

request(base_url) |> 
  req_url_path("stations", closest_obs_station_sf$stationIdentifier, "observations") |> 
  req_url_query(
    start = "2024-10-01T00:00:00Z", 
    end   = "2024-10-07T23:59:59Z"
  ) |> 
  req_perform() |> 
  resp_body_json() |> 
  pluck("features") |> 
  map("properties") |> 
  tibble(props = _) |> 
  hoist(props, "timestamp", temp_value = list("temperature", "value")) |> 
  select(-props)


Results:
#> # A tibble: 84 × 2
#>    timestamp                 temp_value
#>    <chr>                          <dbl>
#>  1 2024-10-07T23:51:00+00:00       18.3
#>  2 2024-10-07T22:51:00+00:00       19.4
#>  3 2024-10-07T21:51:00+00:00       20  
#>  4 2024-10-07T20:51:00+00:00       21.7
#>  5 2024-10-07T19:51:00+00:00       22.2
#>  6 2024-10-07T18:51:00+00:00       22.8
#>  7 2024-10-07T17:51:00+00:00       23.3
#>  8 2024-10-07T16:51:00+00:00       23.9
#>  9 2024-10-07T15:51:00+00:00       22.2
#> 10 2024-10-07T14:51:00+00:00       19.4
#> # ℹ 74 more rows

Created on 2024-10-11 with reprex v2.1.1
